# Autoconf and init scripts

Tags: makefile, autoconf

I'm having trouble understanding how the `autoconf` toolchain deals with init scripts - scripts that are generally placed in `/etc/init.d/` to start/stop daemons or services.

The `autoconf` toolchain specifies a bunch of prenamed installation directory variables, like `$bindir` (where executables go, usually `/usr/local/bin`) or `$includedir` (for header files, probably `/usr/include`), and so on.

But what about init files that go in `/etc/init.d`?  Reading over the **[list of directory variables](https://www.sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_106.html)**, I don't see anything that matches something like `/etc/init.d/`

So what is the usual practice here?  Do I just need to pick an installation directory variable and override it with `AC_SUBST` so I can install scripts to `/etc/init.d`?

Comment: This is a good question, I hope you don't mind the extra info which you didn't ask for.  Since there's a time gap and no accepted answer I've posted a very detailed answer which is also meant to act as a reminder for myself. When I search for these details myself your question is one of the first to appear on Google for my paraphrasing.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest answer; within the top level source directory Makefile.am:

```
# Install my_script in $(bindir) and distribute it.
dist_bin_SCRIPTS = my_script
```

So, `$(bindir)` is the default for scripts.

--

For a more robust implementation that actually covers init scripts for daemons/services (*first quoting the authoritative source*):

> There is no need for EXTRA_DIST or any build rule: Automake infers them from AC_CONFIG_FILES (see Requirements). CLEANFILES is still useful, because by default Automake will clean targets of AC_CONFIG_FILES in distclean, not clean.

Link to source (http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Scripts.html):

**Examples**:

*Install to a custom location:*

```
# Yes, even though its `init_d_SCRIPTS`, we use `init_ddir`,
# with-out a second underscore.
init_ddir = $(sysconfdir)/rc.d/init.d
init_d_SCRIPTS = <yourscript>
# CLEANFILES = $(init_d_SCRIPTS)
```

Please note that `$(sysconfdir)` represents `$(prefix)/etc`; the base path to `init.d` or `rc.d/init.d`, and you can/should(?) *un*-comment the `CLEANFILES` line in either example if your init script is generated by Autotools.

*Or install to the default location:*

```
bin_SCRIPTS = <yourscript>
# CLEANFILES = $(bin_SCRIPTS)
```

Which will be `$(bindir)`

**EDIT**:

Both examples above assume you are having Autotools generate the `init_d_SCRIPTS` files, but what if we want to distribute an already created script instead and have that installed into our `$(init_ddir)` location?

```
init_ddir = $(sysconfdir)/init.d
dist_init_d_SCRIPTS = <yourscript>
```

The trick is that `dist` does not need to be followed by `_bin_SCRIPTS`, it can be `dist_<your_var>_SCRIPTS`. The primary `SCRIPTS` lets Autotools know the value is a script and how to handle it, while the keyword `dist` in the front alerts Automake to the fact that it is not going to be creating a file for us - and instructs Automake not to look for a makefile template in the script source directory.

I wanted to add this little edit since I just had to make the correction myself for a script I'm distributing with my source.

--

**Extra**

For those who will next worry about their init script with regard to packaging (specifically Debian packaging) - which makes this a reminder for myself more or less -> look here:

https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#initd

The error(s) I was getting included debuild trying to install the init.d file and conf file directly in `/etc` and `/etc/init.d` in the root of my filesystem, rather than in `debian/<package>/<location>` like it's supposed to during a package build.

I found that ultimately I had to remove an added rule that was provided in the Packaging Tutorial(s) for Debian where they have you override `dh_auto_install`. Specifically this bit in `debian/rules`:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
    dh $@

# If installing an upstream init.d script:
override_dh_installinit:
    dh_installinit --name=<scriptname> --onlyscripts

# Remove the following:
# override_dh_auto_install:
#    $(MAKE) DESTDIR=$$(pwd)/debian/<package> prefix=/usr install
```

After removing that rule (which wasn't necessary to remove until after adding my init.d script and conf file) everything generated and compiled absolutely perfectly....Including - in fact - dropping the bins into their destination using `/usr` prefix as was the desired effect of the override in the first place.

The override to the `dh_installinit` call tells debuild not to install the init script as the makefile will, and specifies to only make update-rc.d calls to register the script with the system. I chose to name the script different from the package; and so I was required to pass the --name= option.

Hope that helps someone, I know it'll help me in the future if this answer is allowed to remain in existence.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/automake/2007-02/msg00043.html) (addmittely somewhat dated), Autotools may not be well suited for this.  Nevertheless, these instructions were provided (reproduced with small modifications):

```
EXTRA_DIST = bootscript

install-exec-hook:
        cp $(srcdir)/bootscript /etc/init.d
        cd /etc/rc3.d && $(LN_S) ../init.d/bootscript S900bootscript
        cd /etc/rc4.d && $(LN_S) ../init.d/bootscript S900bootscript
        cd /etc/rc5.d && $(LN_S) ../init.d/bootscript S900bootscript
```